# How to change the path prefix of RabbitMQ using nginx

Tags: nginx, rabbitmq

When we enable the RabbitMQ Web Management Console then it is accessible by http://ip:15672.
Instead of this i want to access  RabbitMQ managment console by this http://ip/rabitmq by using nginx

I have done changes in the nginx.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  location /rabbitmq {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:15672;
  }
}
```

but i dont know how to configure path prefix in rabbitnq ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read:
https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/249

In short, you can configure this in the /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf by adding the following line:
management.path_prefix = /rabbitmq

If you are running in a docker environment, you will need to modify:

```
location /rabbitmq {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:15672;
}
```

to

```
location /rabbitmq {
    proxy_pass http://CONTAINERS_HOSTNAME:15672;
}
```